# Major issues with 21.10 (most likely related to sleep mode)

Tags: suspend, desktop-environments, 21.10

some weeks ago I finally upgraded from 21.04 to 21.10. Mainly because I hoped that I would get rid of an issue that - out of the blue - froze my whole desktop every once in a while. There was no way to fix it (the system didn't react to magic keys and stuff) except for a reboot.

Now with 21.10 things are even worse. I start to believe that "every once in a while" is actually "after the laptop was woken up from sleep" because on a freshly booted system I have no issues at all, but after the system came back from sleep mode, this is what happens:

- the overview of open apps (super key) doesn't render (it's just an empty page)
- if I search for apps (also super key), no results are displayed (again an empty page). I can still hit enter and if my search matches an app, it will be started
- Bluetooth fails. Doesn't accept connections, can't connect new devices. Devices that had been connected before sleep might still be shown as connected (without any way to disconnect) while they are physically not
- if an external display was disconnected during sleep, the system won't recognize the change and the mouse pointer still leaves the screen to the external display.
- USB thumb drives won't be recognized (I didn't check for other types of USB device types)
- and the freeze still occurs, but the computer recovers after a couple of seconds (that's an improvement at least XD)

I tried the different window manager options that I can choose on login but I couldn't see much of a difference.

It seems like some major internal process can't handle the sleep mode very well but I have no idea what it could be. My system is a ThinkPad T14 (1. Gen) and it is the AMD version.

Do you have any ideas on how I can fix/debug this? I'm quite firm with interacting with the system but I don't know all the details about the internals of Ubuntu. My research didn't yield any results that brought me further, so I kindly ask for your ideas/support.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I notice some, but not all, of these failures. I need to do Alt + F2 and enter `restart` to get things going again. Does that help in your case?

Comment: Yes, a restart helps always. With 21.10 this still works via the power off menu (or via the power button). With 21.04, not even Alt + F2 was recognized when the system was frozen, so the power button was the only way to reboot.

Comment: @Jos: do you - by any chance - have an AMD system as well? This is just a wild guess, but as I don't read much about those issues in the support forums, I suspect that it might have something to do with my (in 2021) still rather exotic hardware...

Comment: I had also experienced  a related issue couple of week back. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1382888/ubuntu-21-1-wont-exit-deep-sleep-had-to-do-hard-reboot.

Comment: @AjayC: not exactly the same issue but might be related...

Comment: Unfortunately, it may indeed be related to sleep, in combination with proprietary drivers (AMD). So your only workaround may be not to use sleep state.

Comment: No, this is an Intel system, with Intel graphics. I am running on Wayland, that may be relevant.

Comment: @vanadium: so you have any sources for that?